# Get variable value from aspx and use it in code behind

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I am having a little issue. I have a drop down list which can have multiple values selected. I did that by simply adding a `$('#id').attr('multiple','multiple');` 
I know there is a simple way of accessing variable from code behind to aspx page but now i need the opposite thing, because when I multiselect it, from the code file it doesn't recognize the multiselection but only takes 1 value. So basicly I was hoping for something like 
`var temp  = $('#id').val();` --- It takes the selected items correctly

```
<% simplevariable= %> = temp;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a [HiddenField](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hiddenfield%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hiddenField" runat="server" />
```

Set its value like

```
$("#<%=hiddenField.ClientID%>").val($('#id').val())
```

You can use [HiddenField.Value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hiddenfield.value%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in code behind